# htaccess - Set all EN pages to statuscode 410

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-410

I'm trying to set all EN pages of a website to the statuscode 410. The URLs look like this:

```
https://example.com/en/terms-and-conditions/
https://example.com/en/sitemap/
https://example.com/en/category/page-1/
https://example.com/en/category/page-2/
https://example.com/en/category/page-3/subpage-1/
```

I tried different things, but none worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en(/.*)?$  - [G,NC]
```

this also didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en(.*)$ - [NC,R=410,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove `/` after `^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rewrite rules are used in `.htaccess` the URL path doesn't start with `/` because that is the current "base" for the rewrite rules. This is different that when rewrite rules are used in Apache's `.conf` files where the path *does* start with `/`.

I recommend writing rules that can be used in either place by making the starting slash optional.  You just need to add a `?` after the starting slash:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?en(/.*)?$  - [G,NC]
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thank you!